# Eclipse to Android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

So I have a project done which I made in Eclipse, I have also exported it as a Android and somehow imported it in Android Studio, But when I run the program in Android studio, it will execute as Java. And what I want to do is to make it execute in a Android phone (Can also be in a simulator)

But I have not found any tutorials on how to do it and I really need to do it since the essay is ending soon. So I would appreciate all help!

If more info needed, Please, Just comment. I will be available here next 2 hours!

Comment: See this, official documentation http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Comment: Yes, I have already done it. But the problem is that I dont really know how to make it on a phone simulator in the Android studio:/

Comment: This describes two different methods http://www.developer.com/ws/android/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio.html

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I will try that now!

Comment: This explains how to run/debug it https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html

Comment: So i have done this: http://gyazo.com/7fa2a86fc502905d9d42725c3cc83006

Comment: Seems you are not assigning id properly in your activity_mail.xml. See the error text on editor

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Could you help me via Teamviewer if you have some time :)? I would really appreciate it! and I will comment right after here how to make this soulotion

Comment: Sorry I am in office and it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Oh, But so it means I have imported it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The process should be quite simple if you have already succeeded in importing the project into Android Studio.

If you are using a Mac the process is very simple. If you are using Windows then there is one additional step described below:

1. In the AndroidManifest.xml make sure you have android:debuggable="true.
2. If you are using an Android phone with API 4.0+ then go into the phone's Settings and click on About Phone seven times. This might seem like a strange thing to do but it unlocks the phone's developer options, which are hidden by default. On older phones just go to Settings -> Applications -> Development.
   In the Developer options select to allow USB debugging.
3. Now, connect the phone to the computer using a USB cable. You will probably see a message on the phone asking you to authorise the computer for that phone.
4. Next, open Android Studio and run your application (using the green triangle in the top toolbar). If the arrow is greyed-out then then there was a problem importing or building the project.
5. Wait while the project builds. It isn't that obvious that the project is being built. The only indication might be that there is a small spinner. If the build process succeeds you will see a prompt to choose a device. Your phone should be listed there. If it isn't, try disconnecting the phone from the USB and reconnecting it.
6. Select your phone, click OK and away you go. The application should launch on the phone after a few seconds. If it doesn't, be patient sometimes it takes a while. If it still doesn't work, check back in Android Studio for any errors.

Windows Only: Windows requires the additional step of installing the phone's drivers. Details can be found here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: Hmm, So I Have done this right now: http://gyazo.com/7fa2a86fc502905d9d42725c3cc83006              and i have been stuck, I cant get it to a emoultion! Could someone please help me :/?

Comment: Looks like somewhere in activity_main.xml there an element that has an empty id. It will look something like this android:id="@+id/", but it should be something like android:id="@+id/my_id", where 'my_id' is whatever you want to call that element

Comment: Hmm, Is it possible that you could help me via teamviewer if possible? I really have been in front of this 3 hours and im coming no where:/ There isnt any tutroials in youtube aswell ...

Comment: I can't, but it looks like you are pretty close to a running build. Try commenting out troublesome code, if all else fails, if you are not sure how to fix it. You can come back to it once you have a build running on your phone.

Comment: I have already no ideas how to go forward :/ But yeah, I will tune in tommorow and see how it will go! :/(